# Accessing resources in the package of an application created with xcode/cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode

I am trying to make a simple that needs to create an NSImage and I want to put the .png file in the resources of my package contents.  I added the .png file to my resources directory in Xcode and when I create the applicaiton the .png file shows up in my resources inside package contents but I am havhing trouble figuring out how to reference file here is what I tried:

```
[image initWithContentsOfFile:@"resources/draw-button.png"];
```

I figured that my package contents would be my current directory so I thought this would work, but it does.  How do I reference my resources directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use [`NSBundle`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"draw-button" ofType:@"png"];
NSImage *img = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Comment: Not necessary for images (see Frank Schmitt's answer). Also, paths must be absolute, not relative. Even if paths could be relative to the executable, "resources/..." is still incorrect, since the app bundle is not the same thing as the executable *in* the bundle. :-)

Comment: `-[NSBundle pathForResource:ofType]` *does* return an absolute path. (Also, `UIImage` is a Cocoa Touch class, not a Cocoa class.)

Answer (score 4):

Try `[UIImage imageNamed:@"draw-button.png"]`.

"Resources" is just an organizational category in XCode, not a true folder in the application bundle.

Comment: Or NSImage, in the questioner's case.